# How to optimize APIs function with the same header

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using fetch to deal with the API, I must add a header into every single API function like below. It's duplicate so much.

```
getSomething: async() => {
    const user: IUserData = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")!),
      userCompanies: ICompanies = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("companies")!),
      companyId = Object.keys(userCompanies.Company)[0], meId = user.userInfo.data.id, myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("authorization", user.accessToken.token);
    myHeaders.append("company-id", companyId);

    const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
      headers: myHeaders,
      method: "GET",
      redirect: "follow"
    };

    return fetch(url + `/${meId}/calendars?type=tree`, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => result)
      .catch((error) => error);
  }
```

How can I reduce or optimize them?

Comment: Make abstraction over fetch, e.g get method that you would use instead of fetch, and inside that get method you would use fetch and add all those things. That means that you would only pass url and query params to get method.

Comment: Do you have any example? @zhuber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try abstracting `fetch` by making your own `GET` method, e.g.

```
async function get(url: string, options?: RequestInit) {
    const user: IUserData = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")!);
    const userCompanies: ICompanies = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("companies")!);
    const companyId = Object.keys(userCompanies.Company)[0];
    const meId = user.userInfo.data.id;
    
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("authorization", user.accessToken.token);
    myHeaders.append("company-id", companyId);
    
  const baseOptions: RequestInit = {
    headers: myHeaders,
    method: "GET",
    redirect: "follow"
  };

  // merge passed options with your baseOptions

  let baseUrl = 'your-base-url';
  return fetch(baseUrl + `/${meId}/${url}`, baseOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => result)
    .catch((error) => error);
}

getSomething: async() => {
  return get('/calendars?type=tree')
}
```

This is just an idea, because I'm not sure which parameters are reusable over many different requests. You might even end up with `baseGet` which handles only core functionality shared for all requests, then have `baseCompanyGet` which is abstraction of `baseGet` and is used only by company requests, etc..

The idea is to identify code that is being repeated and put it in some kind of base method, while you pass only dynamic data via method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the way you could do that is by grouping it in a storage class that you find helpful when accessing the data

```
//Setter
localStorage.setItem('myHeaders', data);
// getter
localStorage.getItem('myHeaders');
```

To  work with local storage have a look at this article
https://medium.com/@siobhanpmahoney/local-storage-in-a-react-single-page-application-34ba30fc977d

Comment: store in data what you like to store and save it using a key named myheader or the value of the header name